# conectar dos contenedores en docker

Tags: php, docker, curl

tengo dos contenedores en mi pc local, el contenedor uno esta en http://localhost:80
y el segundo esta en http://localhost:8100.
Necesito hacer una peticion curl(PHP) del primer contenedor http://localhost:80  al segundo http://localhost:8100, pero no logro conectarlos. segui esta guia [guia crear red docker](https://medium.com/it-dead-inside/docker-containers-and-localhost-cannot-assign-requested-address-6ac7bc0d042b) para crear una red y conectarlos los dos a la red.

esta es la red creada

```
docker network create nueva-red
```

este es el archivo docker-compose.yml se mi http://localhost:80

```
  ports:
  - '80:80'
 networks:
  - nueva-red

 networks:
   nueva-red:
   external: true

environment:
  - API_URL=Api:5000
```

Este es la configuracion de mi segundo contenedor en docker-compose.yml http://localhost:8100

```
   ports:
  - "0.0.0.0:5555:5000"

  networks:
  - nueva-red

  networks:
  nueva-red:
  external: true
```

En el controlador de http://localhost:80 tengo la siguiente llamada que no me esta funcionando actualmente desde contenedores

```
    $curl = curl_init('http://Api:5000/api/folio');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);/** Autorizamos enviar datos*/
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); //mostrar la conexion
```

agradezco toda la ayuda posible

Comment: Varias cosas: 1) Uno puede crear un segmento de red interno pa que los contenedores lo usen; 2) Revisa el indentado de los YML; 3) Revisa que sí puedas usar el puerto 80, pues es posible que el OS no te lo permita :)  4) Validaste que cada servicio inicie correctamente y esté disponible?

Comment: 1. Com lo podría hacer? 2. Revisado 3. Si esta en uso. 4. Estan arriba

Comment: proba [`getenv('API_URL')`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.getenv.php) que la estas definiendo en el yaml